# Problem with result shape when running Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to make prediction with Keras Neural Network. My output data has 3 different values -1,0,1.
When I run my NN I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_35 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Then I tried to do:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import to_categorical
results = to_categorical(results)
```

But again I get the same error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_35 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
features = df.iloc[:,-8:]
results = df.iloc[:,-9]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim = x_train.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# call the function to fit to the data training the network)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=0, verbose=1, mode='auto')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, shuffle = True, batch_size=128, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2, callbacks=[es])
```

Comment: Yes, In model fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results = df.iloc[:,-9]` you're choosing 1-d output (shape: (rows,1)), but your last layer has 3 units `model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))`.

So, your result must have shape: (rows, 3) not (rows, 1).

I see your result has values -1, 0, 1. Just add one so that they are 0, 1, 2. That's why you're getting error with `to_categorical`; according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical), it expects

> **`y`**: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to num_classes).

So go for

`results = results + 1`

Then, apply `to_categorical`.

After that `fit` should work fine.